# Automatically import YouTube Analytics into Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to import my YouTube analytics into google sheets and have been following this [example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/code_samples/apps-script), but haven't been able to get it to work. I believe I have authorized all approrpriate APIs and created a credentinal. However I've run into errors that I can find the answer to.

My ultimately goal is to automatically import all of my YouTube data (views, avg view duration, shares, gender, age...) into Google Sheets with the appropriate headers and charts.

A couple of the errors I am getting:

Line 18 or my .gs file.

ReferenceError: "google" is not defined. (line 18, file "Code")Dismiss

google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages': ['corechart']});

If I remove line 18-26 I get an error on line 324

TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined. (line 324, file "Code")Dismiss

var numRows = analyticsResponse.rows.length;

Thanks in advance!

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Retrieve your client ID from the {{ Google Cloud Console }} at
  // {{ https://cloud.google.com/console }}.
  var OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'XXXXXXXX';
  var OAUTH2_SCOPES = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly'
  ];

  var ONE_MONTH_IN_MILLISECONDS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;

  // Keep track of the currently authenticated user's YouTube channel ID.
  var channelId;


  // For information about the Google Chart Tools API, see:
  // https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start
  google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages': ['corechart']});

  // Upon loading, the Google APIs JS client automatically invokes this callback.
  // See https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication 
  window.onJSClientLoad = function() {
    gapi.auth.init(function() {
      window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
    });
  };

 
  // Attempt the immediate OAuth 2.0 client flow as soon as the page loads.
  // If the currently logged-in Google Account has previously authorized
  // the client specified as the OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID, then the authorization
  // succeeds with no user intervention. Otherwise, it fails and the
  // user interface that prompts for authorization needs to display.
  function checkAuth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize({
      client_id: OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
      scope: OAUTH2_SCOPES,
      immediate: true
    }, handleAuthResult);
  }

  // Handle the result of a gapi.auth.authorize() call.
  function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    if (authResult) {
      // Authorization was successful. Hide authorization prompts and show
      // content that should be visible after authorization succeeds.
      $('.pre-auth').hide();
      $('.post-auth').show();

      loadAPIClientInterfaces();
    } else {
      // Authorization was unsuccessful. Show content related to prompting for
      // authorization and hide content that should be visible if authorization
      // succeeds.
      $('.post-auth').hide();
      $('.pre-auth').show();

      // Make the #login-link clickable. Attempt a non-immediate OAuth 2.0
      // client flow. The current function is called when that flow completes.
      $('#login-link').click(function() {
        gapi.auth.authorize({
          client_id: OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
          scope: OAUTH2_SCOPES,
          immediate: false
        }, handleAuthResult);
      });
    }
  }

  // Load the client interfaces for the YouTube Analytics and Data APIs, which
  // are required to use the Google APIs JS client. More info is available at
  // https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/dev/dev_jscript#loading-the-client-library-and-the-api
  function loadAPIClientInterfaces() {
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
      gapi.client.load('youtubeAnalytics', 'v1', function() {
        // After both client interfaces load, use the Data API to request
        // information about the authenticated user's channel.
        getUserChannel();
      });
    });
  }

  // Call the Data API to retrieve information about the currently
  // authenticated user's YouTube channel.
  function getUserChannel() {
    // Also see: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.channels.list({
      // Setting the "mine" request parameter's value to "true" indicates that
      // you want to retrieve the currently authenticated user's channel.
      mine: true,
      part: 'id,contentDetails'
    });

    request.execute(function(response) {
      if ('error' in response) {
        displayMessage(response.error.message);
      } else {
        // We need the channel's channel ID to make calls to the Analytics API.
        // The channel ID value has the form "UCdLFeWKpkLhkguiMZUp8lWA".
        channelId = response.items[0].id;
        // Retrieve the playlist ID that uniquely identifies the playlist of
        // videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel. This value has
        // the form "UUdLFeWKpkLhkguiMZUp8lWA".
        var uploadsListId = response.items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
        // Use the playlist ID to retrieve the list of uploaded videos.
        getPlaylistItems(uploadsListId);
      }
    });
  }

  // Call the Data API to retrieve the items in a particular playlist. In this
  // example, we are retrieving a playlist of the currently authenticated user's
  // uploaded videos. By default, the list returns the most recent videos first.
  function getPlaylistItems(listId) {
    // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistitems/list
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list({
      playlistId: listId,
      part: 'snippet'
    });

    request.execute(function(response) {
      if ('error' in response) {
        displayMessage(response.error.message);
      } else {
        if ('items' in response) {
          // The jQuery.map() function iterates through all of the items in
          // the response and creates a new array that only contains the
          // specific property we're looking for: videoId.
          var videoIds = $.map(response.items, function(item) {
            return item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;
          });

          // Now that we know the IDs of all the videos in the uploads list,
          // we can retrieve information about each video.
          getVideoMetadata(videoIds);
        } else {
          displayMessage('There are no videos in your channel.');
        }
      }
    });
  }

  // Given an array of video IDs, this function obtains metadata about each
  // video and then uses that metadata to display a list of videos.
  function getVideoMetadata(videoIds) {
    // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.videos.list({
      // The 'id' property's value is a comma-separated string of video IDs.
      id: videoIds.join(','),
      part: 'id,snippet,statistics'
    });

    request.execute(function(response) {
      if ('error' in response) {
        displayMessage(response.error.message);
      } else {
        // Get the jQuery wrapper for the #video-list element before starting
        // the loop.
        var videoList = $('#video-list');
        $.each(response.items, function() {
          // Exclude videos that do not have any views, since those videos
          // will not have any interesting viewcount Analytics data.
          if (this.statistics.viewCount == 0) {
            return;
          }

          var title = this.snippet.title;
          var videoId = this.id;

          // Create a new <li> element that contains an <a> element.
          // Set the <a> element's text content to the video's title, and
          // add a click handler that will display Analytics data when invoked.
          var liElement = $('<li>');
          var aElement = $('<a>');
          // Setting the href value to '#' ensures that the browser renders the
          // <a> element as a clickable link.
          aElement.attr('href', '#');
          aElement.text(title);
          aElement.click(function() {
            displayVideoAnalytics(videoId);
          });

          // Call the jQuery.append() method to add the new <a> element to
          // the <li> element, and the <li> element to the parent
          // list, which is identified by the 'videoList' variable.
          liElement.append(aElement);
          videoList.append(liElement);
        });

        if (videoList.children().length == 0) {
          // Display a message if the channel does not have any viewed videos.
          displayMessage('Your channel does not have any videos that have been viewed.');
        }
      }
    });
  }

  // This function requests YouTube Analytics data for a video and displays
  // the results in a chart.
  function displayVideoAnalytics(videoId) {
    if (channelId) {
      // To use a different date range, modify the ONE_MONTH_IN_MILLISECONDS
      // variable to a different millisecond delta as desired.
      var today = new Date();
      var lastMonth = new Date(today.getTime() - ONE_MONTH_IN_MILLISECONDS);

      var request = gapi.client.youtubeAnalytics.reports.query({
        // The start-date and end-date parameters must be YYYY-MM-DD strings.
        'start-date': formatDateString(lastMonth),
        'end-date': formatDateString(today),
        // At this time, you need to explicitly specify channel==channelId.
        // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/#ids
        ids: 'channel==' + channelId,
        dimensions: 'day',
        sort: 'day',
        // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/available_reports
        // for details about the different filters and metrics you can request
        // if the "dimensions" parameter value is "day".
        metrics: 'views',
        filters: 'video==' + videoId
      });

      request.execute(function(response) {
        // This function is called regardless of whether the request succeeds.
        // The response contains YouTube Analytics data or an error message.
        if ('error' in response) {
          displayMessage(response.error.message);
        } else {
          displayChart(videoId, response);
        }
      });
    } else {
      // The currently authenticated user's channel ID is not available.
      displayMessage('The YouTube channel ID for the current user is not available.');
    }
  }

  // This boilerplate code takes a Date object and returns a YYYY-MM-DD string.
  function formatDateString(date) {
    var yyyy = date.getFullYear().toString();
    var mm = padToTwoCharacters(date.getMonth() + 1);
    var dd = padToTwoCharacters(date.getDate());

    return yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
  }

  // If number is a single digit, prepend a '0'. Otherwise, return the number
  //  as a string.
  function padToTwoCharacters(number) {
    if (number < 10) {
      return '0' + number;
    } else {
      return number.toString();
    }
  }

  // Call the Google Chart Tools API to generate a chart of Analytics data.
  function displayChart(videoId, response) {
    if ('rows' in response) {
      hideMessage();

      // The columnHeaders property contains an array of objects representing
      // each column's title -- e.g.: [{name:"day"},{name:"views"}]
      // We need these column titles as a simple array, so we call jQuery.map()
      // to get each element's "name" property and create a new array that only
      // contains those values.
      var columns = $.map(response.columnHeaders, function(item) {
        return item.name;
      });
      // The google.visualization.arrayToDataTable() function wants an array
      // of arrays. The first element is an array of column titles, calculated
      // above as "columns". The remaining elements are arrays that each
      // represent a row of data. Fortunately, response.rows is already in
      // this format, so it can just be concatenated.
      // See https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews#arraytodatatable
      var chartDataArray = [columns].concat(response.rows);
      var chartDataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartDataArray);

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
      chart.draw(chartDataTable, {
        // Additional options can be set if desired as described at:
        // https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#visdraw
        title: 'Views per Day of Video ' + videoId
      });
    } else {
      displayMessage('No data available for video ' + videoId);
    }
  }

  // This helper method displays a message on the page.
  function displayMessage(message) {
    $('#message').text(message).show();
  }

  // This helper method hides a previously displayed message on the page.
  function hideMessage() {
    $('#message').hide();
  }


}

function spreadsheetAnalytics() {
  // Get the channel ID
  var myChannels = YouTube.Channels.list('id', {mine: true});
  var channel = myChannels.items[0];
  var channelId = channel.id;

  // Set the dates for our report
  var today = new Date();
  var oneMonthAgo = new Date();
  oneMonthAgo.setMonth(today.getMonth() - 1);
  var todayFormatted = Utilities.formatDate(today, 'UTC', 'yyyy-MM-dd')
  var oneMonthAgoFormatted = Utilities.formatDate(oneMonthAgo, 'UTC', 'yyyy-MM-dd');

  // The YouTubeAnalytics.Reports.query() function has four required parameters and one optional
  // parameter. The first parameter identifies the channel or content owner for which you are
  // retrieving data. The second and third parameters specify the start and end dates for the
  // report, respectively. The fourth parameter identifies the metrics that you are retrieving.
  // The fifth parameter is an object that contains any additional optional parameters
  // (dimensions, filters, sort, etc.) that you want to set.
  var analyticsResponse = YouTubeAnalytics.Reports.query(
    'channel==' + channelId,
    oneMonthAgoFormatted,
    todayFormatted,
    'views,likes,dislikes,shares',
    {
      dimensions: 'day',
      sort: '-day'
    });

  // Create a new Spreadsheet with rows and columns corresponding to our dates
  var ssName = 'YouTube channel report ' + oneMonthAgoFormatted + ' - ' + todayFormatted;
  var numRows = analyticsResponse.rows.length;
  var numCols = analyticsResponse.columnHeaders.length;
  
  // Add an extra row for column headers
  var ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.create(ssName, numRows + 1, numCols);

  // Get the first sheet
  var sheet = ssNew.getSheets()[0];

  // Get the range for the title columns
  // Remember, spreadsheets are 1-indexed, whereas arrays are 0-indexed
  var headersRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, numCols);
  var headers = [];

  // These column headers will correspond with the metrics requested
  // in the initial call: views, likes, dislikes, shares
  for(var i in analyticsResponse.columnHeaders) {
    var columnHeader = analyticsResponse.columnHeaders[i];
    var columnName = columnHeader.name;
    headers[i] = columnName;
  }
  // This takes a 2 dimensional array
  headersRange.setValues([headers]);

  // Bold and freeze the column names
  headersRange.setFontWeight('bold');
  sheet.setFrozenRows(1);

  // Get the data range and set the values
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, numRows, numCols);
  dataRange.setValues(analyticsResponse.rows);

  // Bold and freeze the dates
  var dateHeaders = sheet.getRange(1, 1, numRows, 1);
  dateHeaders.setFontWeight('bold');
  sheet.setFrozenColumns(1);

  // Include the headers in our range. The headers are used
  // to label the axes
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, numRows, numCols);
  var chart = sheet.newChart()
                   .asColumnChart()
                   .setStacked()
                   .addRange(range)
                   .setPosition(4, 2, 10, 10)
                   .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);

}
```

I've attached a screenshot of my current setup and attached my .gs file.

Answer (score 0):

Apps Script is server side programming language. Instead of using the client side JavaScript library it uses its own built in services to access google APIs. It also has authorization and authentication baked into the platform via OAuth2. Take a look at the analytics example below. When `createReport` is ran it will get the analytics for your youtube channel and save them to a new spreadsheet. Look at `recents` in drive for the report.

To adapt this to your needs take a look at the metrics array.

```
 /**
 * Creates a spreadsheet containing daily view counts, watch-time metrics,
 * and new-subscriber counts for a channel's videos.
 */
function createReport() {
  // Retrieve info about the user's YouTube channel.
  var channels = YouTube.Channels.list('id,contentDetails', {
    "mine":true
  });
  var channelId = channels.items[0].id;

  // Retrieve analytics report for the channel.
  var oneMonthInMillis = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
  var today = new Date();
  var lastMonth = new Date(today.getTime() - oneMonthInMillis);

  var metrics = [
    'views',
    'estimatedMinutesWatched',
    'averageViewDuration',
    'averageViewPercentage',
    'subscribersGained'
  ];
  var options = {
    dimensions: 'day',
    sort: 'day'
  };
  var result = YouTubeAnalytics.Reports.query('channel==' + channelId,
      formatDateString(lastMonth),
      formatDateString(today),
      metrics.join(','),
      options);

  if (result.rows) {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create('YouTube Analytics Report');
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

    // Append the headers.
    var headers = result.columnHeaders.map(function(columnHeader) {
      return formatColumnName(columnHeader.name);
    });
    sheet.appendRow(headers);

    // Append the results.
    sheet.getRange(2, 1, result.rows.length, headers.length)
        .setValues(result.rows);

    Logger.log('Report spreadsheet created: %s',
        spreadsheet.getUrl());
  } else {
    Logger.log('No rows returned.');
  }
}

/*
 * Converts a Date object into a YYYY-MM-DD string.
 */
function formatDateString(date) {
  return Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
}

/*
 * Formats a column name into a more human-friendly name. For example
 * "averageViewPercentage" becomes "Average View Percentage".
 */
function formatColumnName(columnName) {
  var name = columnName.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2');
  name = name.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1);
  return name;
}
```